# Avoid stopping of Julia for REST service

Tags: rest, julia

I try to build a little REST service with Julia and Genie library. The last command is `up(8888)`.

When I start this from Julia REPL all is ok.

When I start it from command line like `>julia myrestapi.jl` the program starts and stops immediately, i.e. `up()` doesn't go into an infinite loop.

What can I do to keep the server running?

Comment: From other Julia server examples on the internet, they use: `Base.JLOptions().isinteractive == 0 && wait()` at end of script.

Comment: I use this pattern in https://github.com/bkamins/JuliaForDataAnalysis/blob/main/ch14_server.jl and have not noticed the issue you report. Can you please check my script on your machine? Maybe you missed `Genie.config.run_as_server = true` configuration option?

Comment: ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: Server not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] getproperty(x::Module, f::Symbol)
   @ Base .\Base.jl:35
 [2] top-level scope
   @ C:\Micha\Programming\Julia\rest2.jl:50
in expression starting at C:\Micha\Programming\Julia\rest2.jl:50

Comment: @Dan Getz : Simply wait() did the job. You can post it as answer/solution. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelHecht The `run_as_server` method looks more idiomatic, so if you try it, and it doesn't work, I'll post the `wait` as answer (be sure to have updated Julia and package versions, as this usually is a cause of problems)

Comment: I installed Genie today, so it should be the newest version. Julia is 1.7.3. What causes the error is Genie.Server.up(). Genie.config.run_as_server = true gives no visible change in behaviour, that's why I thought I can skip it.

Answer (score 2):

When the Genie server is initiated in asynchronous mode, it runs off the main Task, and allows script processing to continue. If the script ends, the whole process and its spawned Tasks are stopped. This behavior is not good for a running web-service. To keep this from happening, two suggestions are:

1. Don't run the server off the main Task, by running synchronously. In code:

```
Genie.config.run_as_server = true
...
Genie.Server.up()
```

2. Make sure the main process does not end until the server Task ends. In code:

```
Base.JLOptions().isinteractive == 0 && wait()
```

The `isinteractive` condition, runs the `wait()` only when it is running as a script, as the usual desire when a REPL is present in interactive session, is to issue more commands, and the REPL keeps the server Task running in the background.